# Using a BREAK statement to exit this while loop changes the value of the variable and gives incorrect answer. Need another way?

Tags: python, while-loop, square-root

**Question:**

Write a program that implements Newton’s method to compute and display the square
root of a number entered by the user. The algorithm for Newton’s method follows:
Read x from the user
Initialize guess to x/2
While guess is not good enough do
Update guess to be the average of guess and x/guess
When this algorithm completes, guess contains an approximation of the square root. The quality of the approximation depends on how you define “good enough”. In the author’s solution, guess was considered good enough when the absolute value of the difference between guess ∗ guess and x was less than or equal to 10−12.

Solution:

```py
x = int(input("Enter x: "))

guess = x/2

while guess != (abs(guess * guess - x <= 10 ** -12)):

    guess =  (guess + x/guess)/2

    print(guess)
```

Note: if I add a break statement, it changes the value.
Ex: square root of 9 = 3 using the above solution.

but If I add a BREAK statement...

```
while guess != (abs(guess * guess - x <= 10 ** -12)):

    guess =  (guess + x/guess)/2

    print(guess)

    break
```

Enter x: 9
3.25

why does adding a break statement change the value of the guess variable? How do I terminate this loop without changing the value and simply print guess and exit loop?

endloop is not working and exit() seems to have the same effect. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you !

```py
if type(guess) != str:
    break
```

I have also tried placing such a condition. same effect. prints incorrect value for guess.

Comment: The expression in your `while` statement is basically nonsense.  What you meant to say is `while abs(guess*guess - x) >= 10**-12:`.  What you have will just loop infinitely.  Adding the `break` stops the loop, but of course it stops it before it has converged.

Comment: Right... but that "nonsense" statement actually gives out the correct answer.
Ex: 9 --> 3 . I have tried implementing your statement as well, but it changes the answer completely.

Comment: @Sameen With an input value of 9, the correct result is 3. However, although your first code fragment gives the right result it does so *ad infinitum*. If you add *break* then the calculation (estimation) will only be performed once

Comment: Your code prints 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0. 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0....  That's hardly a "correct" answer.  My code works -- you must have typed it wrong.  It converges after 5 loops.  Did you notice the `<=` needed to become `>=`?

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates the correct while condition:

```
x = int(input("Enter x: "))
guess = x/2
while abs(guess * guess - x) >= 10 ** -12:
    guess =  (guess + x/guess)/2
    print(guess)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
Enter x: 9
3.25
3.0096153846153846
3.000015360039322
3.0000000000393214
3.0
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question... I didn't realize that the loop had to keep iterating or 'guessing' until it got to the right answer.  Now I see my error. Thank you so much for your help, Tim!

Comment: If you only want the final answer, shift the `print` left one level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach that uses an extra variable and thus a less complicated conditional expression. Also use a variable to determine the level of accuracy and also use that same variable to the presentation of the result.

```
x = float(input('X: '))

guess = x / 2
prev = x

DP = 4 # no. of decimal places accuracy
MARGIN = 10 ** -DP

while abs(guess - prev) > MARGIN:
    prev = guess
    guess = (guess + x / guess) / 2

print(f'{guess:.{DP}f}')
```

**Example:**

```
X: 17
4.1231
```

Comment: Hi Fred! Thank you so sharing your solution

I like that this solution prints out the correct answer right away but I am struggling a bit to understand how it works. Can you please explain :

while abs(guess - prev) > MARGIN:

does this mean (4.5 - 9 ) > 0.0001?

Also why did you set MARGIN to 10 ** -4 ?

I know this solution works but I am trying to understand why it works. Will very much appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: It's not comparing the guess to the original number.  It's comparing this guess to the previous guess.  When the guesses converge, you have the answer.

Comment: @Sameen I set DP to 4 as an example. Note the comment in the code. It explains its purpose